# Is the new historical Twitter search feature available in the API?

Tags: twitter

Twitter [recently announced they built the complete index of tweets](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/building-a-complete-tweet-index) going all the way back. But calling `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json` with `q=ftw%20until:2010-12-27` yields no results, even though this specific example is [explicitly mentioned in their API doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

Can anyone confirm or infirm that the API still does not search the full index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twitter API still doesn't support searching old tweets. It will only return tweets that are  no longer than 7 days old.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any official documentation that states this? Or is that from your own experience?

Comment: I have written a Twitter app for archiving tweets and it only returns tweets that are newer than published in the last week.

Comment: @infojunkie Here is what you ask. https://twittercommunity.com/t/search-api-the-new-complete-tweet-index-announcement/27883/5

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search In best practices section